# Why am I unable to find an html element through jQuery/JS string interoplation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of div blocks each with a unique numerical id.

For example:
[image]

As part of a project I'm working on, I want to select the 29th element after the element I choose. So if I chose the first div with id of `1` then I want to be able to choose div with id `30`. Here is how I am attempting to do this with the first div:

```
let int = parseInt($('.blockattribute').first().attr('id')) + 29;
$('#' + toString(int);
```

This gives me the following error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Undefined]
```

This should work though. By executing `$('#30');`, I'm able to select the div I want. What could be the problem?

Comment: What do you see if you do `console.log(int)`? Also, you're missing a parenthesis after `toString(int)`.

Comment: is it just a typo that this looks like you're missing another bracket? `$('#' + toString(int);` -> `$('#' + toString(int));`

Comment: `$(".blockattribute").eq($(this).index() + 29)` seems like a better way to access the 29th element after the current one.

Comment: The error you're getting indicates that `int` is undefined. `toString(undefined)` returns `"[object Undefined]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) which would return `[object Undefined]` when you do

```
Object.toString(30);
```

you wanted to use [`Number.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) instead, and you'd do that like so

```
let int = parseInt($('.blockattribute').first().attr('id')) + 29;
$('#' + int.toString());
```

but you really don't need it, as concatenating a string and a number returns a string anyway